# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /functions.php on line 155

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trouble-shooting away right now, but coding is not my strong suit, and I know it is some of yours'.

If you could help me figure out what in gosh's name is going on right now, I'd really appreciate it.
Here is my function.php code:

```
<?php
//* Start the engine
include_once( get_template_directory() . '/lib/init.php' );

//* Set Localization (do not remove)
load_child_theme_textdomain( 'sixteen-nine', apply_filters( 'child_theme_textdomain',             get_stylesheet_directory() . '/languages', 'sixteen-nine' ) );

//* Child theme (do not remove)
define( 'CHILD_THEME_NAME', __( 'Sixteen Nine Pro Theme', 'sixteen-nine' ) );
define( 'CHILD_THEME_URL', 'http://my.studiopress.com/themes/sixteen-nine/' );
define( 'CHILD_THEME_VERSION', '1.0' );

//* Add HTML5 markup structure
add_theme_support( 'html5' );

//* Add viewport meta tag for mobile browsers
add_theme_support( 'genesis-responsive-viewport' );

//* Enqueue Playfair Display and Roboto family of Google fonts
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'sixteen_nine_google_fonts' );
function sixteen_nine_google_fonts() {

wp_enqueue_style( 'google-font', '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?        family=Playfair+Display:300italic|Roboto:300,700|Roboto+Condensed:300,700|Roboto+Slab:300', array(),    PARENT_THEME_VERSION );

}

//* Enqueue Backstretch script and prepare images for loading
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'sixteen_nine_enqueue_scripts' );
function sixteen_nine_enqueue_scripts() {

wp_enqueue_script( 'sixteen-nine-responsive-menu', get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ) .      '/js/responsive-menu.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0' );

//* Load scripts only if custom background is being used
if ( ! get_background_image() )
    return;

wp_enqueue_script( 'sixteen-nine-backstretch', get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ) .     '/js/backstretch.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'sixteen-nine-backstretch-set',    get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory').'/js/backstretch-set.js' , array( 'jquery', 'sixteen-nine-   backstretch' ), '1.0.0' );

wp_localize_script( 'sixteen-nine-backstretch-set', 'BackStretchImg', array( 'src' => str_replace( 'http:', '', get_background_image() ) ) );

}

//* Add custom background callback for background color
function sixteen_nine_background_callback() {

if ( ! get_background_color() )
    return;

printf( '<style>body { background-color: #%s; }</style>' . "\n", get_background_color() );

}

//* Add support for custom background
add_theme_support( 'custom-background', array( 'wp-head-callback' =>     'sixteen_nine_background_callback' ) );

//* Add support for custom header
add_theme_support( 'custom-header', array(
'admin-preview-callback' => 'sixteen_nine_admin_header_callback',
'default-text-color'     => 'ffffff',
'header-selector'        => '.site-header .site-avatar img',
'height'                 => 224,
'width'                  => 224,
'wp-head-callback'       => 'sixteen_nine_header_callback',
) );

function sixteen_nine_admin_header_callback() {
echo get_header_image() ? '<img src="' . get_header_image() . '" />' : get_avatar( get_option( '    admin_email' ), 224 );
}

 function sixteen_nine_header_callback() {

if ( ! get_header_textcolor() )
    return;

printf( '<style  type="text/css">.site-title a { color: #%s; }</style>' . "\n",    get_header_textcolor() );
}

//* Unregister layout settings
genesis_unregister_layout( 'sidebar-content' );
genesis_unregister_layout( 'content-sidebar-sidebar' );
genesis_unregister_layout( 'sidebar-sidebar-content' );
genesis_unregister_layout( 'sidebar-content-sidebar' );

//* Unregister primary/secondary navigation menus
remove_theme_support( 'genesis-menus' );

//* Unregister secondary sidebar
unregister_sidebar( 'sidebar-alt' );

//* Hook site avatar before site title
add_action( 'genesis_header', 'sixteen_nine_site_gravatar', 5 );
function sixteen_nine_site_gravatar() {

$header_image = get_header_image() ? '<img alt="" src="' . get_header_image() . '" />' : get_avatar(      get_option( 'admin_email' ), 224 );

printf( '<div class="site-avatar"><a href="%s">%s</a></div>', home_url( '/' ), $header_image );

}

//* Hook after post widget after the entry content
add_action( 'genesis_after_entry', 'sixteen_nine_after_entry', 5 );
function sixteen_nine_after_entry() {

if ( is_singular( 'post' ) )
    genesis_widget_area( 'after-entry', array(
        'before' => '<div class="after-entry" class="widget-area">',
        'after'  => '</div>',
    ) );

}

//* Modify the size of the Gravatar in the author box
add_filter( 'genesis_author_box_gravatar_size', 'sixteen_nine_author_box_gravatar' );
function sixteen_nine_author_box_gravatar( $size ) {

return 140;

}

//* Modify the size of the Gravatar in the entry comments
add_filter( 'genesis_comment_list_args', 'sixteen_nine_comments_gravatar' );
function sixteen_nine_comments_gravatar( $args ) {

$args['avatar_size'] = 96;

return $args;

}

//* Reposition the footer
remove_action( 'genesis_footer', 'genesis_footer_markup_open', 5 );
remove_action( 'genesis_footer', 'genesis_do_footer' );
remove_action( 'genesis_footer', 'genesis_footer_markup_close', 15 );
add_action( 'genesis_header', 'genesis_footer_markup_open', 11 );
add_action( 'genesis_header', 'genesis_do_footer', 12 );
add_action( 'genesis_header', 'genesis_footer_markup_close', 13 );

//* Customize the footer
add_filter( 'genesis_footer_output', 'sixteen_nine_custom_footer' );
function sixteen_nine_custom_footer( $output ) {

$output = sprintf( '<p>%s<a href="http://www.studiopress.com/">%s</a></p>',  __( 'Powered by ',     'sixteen-nine' ), __( 'Genesis', 'sixteen-nine' ) );
return $output;

}

//* Register widget areas
genesis_register_sidebar( array(
'id'          => 'after-entry',
'name'        => __( 'After Entry', 'sixteen-nine' ),
'description' => __( 'This is the widget that appears after the entry on single posts.', 'sixteen-     nine' ),
) );
```

Comment: The error message says what is the problem. It is exact and accurate. StackOverflow is not a bugfix service. Please try to check the 155th line. (Tip: there is an extra or missing quotation mark somewhere in your code).

Answer (score 0):

The problem doesn't appear to be with this file.  There are no syntax errors in this file.  You are, however, including at least one other file, which could well contain a syntax error.